# Problems with boto 'generate_url' and storing unicode metadata in S3 with fineuploader

Tags: python, unicode, amazon-s3, boto, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader 5.0.1 and have encountered an issue with uploading files that have unicode filenames.  The filename gets encoded in x-amz-meta-qqfilename, an example is: `Test%20%E2%80%93%20My%20File.pdf`.  When I then try to call `generate_url` on the key, it fails in boto with:

```
    return True, k.generate_url(expires_in)
  File "/opt/webapp/sampleapp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 704, in generate_url
    version_id)
  File "/opt/webapp/sampleapp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 408, in generate_url
    expires, self.provider)
  File "/opt/webapp/sampleapp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 122, in canonical_string
    interesting_headers[lk] = str(headers[key]).strip()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I can't work out if this is fineuploader or boto at fault.  Leaning towards the latter - I assume having encoded filenames is valid inside a key's metadata?

The issue is the metadata is decoded on boto's side (i.e. becomes `{'x-amz-meta-qqfilename': u'Test \u2013 My File.pdf'}`), but then the generate_url method copies this metadata into the header and then is expecting everything to be ascii.

Oddly though I can't seem to find anyone else having a similar issue which does make me wonder if I've done something wrong - however I'm not doing anything special on my end, just using fineuploader with minor gui modifications and standard boto version 2.32.1.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an issue with using `str()` to decode unicode in python. Read: https://docs.python.org/2.6/howto/unicode.html, and also check out the first example.

Comment: That's not our code doing that - that's boto. The filename on our end is encoded to UTF-8 then URL encoded.  Boto then seems to unquote it and decode it to unicode, but then call str() on it, which is the cause of the failure.  I'm pretty sure boto is at fault here, but the fact that no one else seems to be having this issue seems very odd to me.  I tried modifying the source to stop decoding the url encoded chars, and now get a signing error with boto.

Comment: Actually I found out the signature encoding error was due to a timing issue on my VM, so removing the url unquoting for the metadata fixes boto's issue.  I'll get in contact with them to see what they think.